# Save BIO into char* (from SMIME_write_CMS)

Tags: ios, iphone, openssl, smime

I want to save (pipe/copy) a BIO into a char array.
When I know the size it works, but otherwise not.

For example, I can store the content of my char* into a BIO using this

```
const unsigned char* data = ...    
myBio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)data, strlen(data));
```

But when I try to use SMIME_write_CMS which takes a BIO (what I've created before) for the output it doesn't work.

```
const int SIZE = 50000;
unsigned char *temp = malloc(SIZE);
memset(temp, 0, SIZE);

out = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)temp, SIZE);
if (!out) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create new file!");
    assert(false);
}


int finished = SMIME_write_CMS(out, cms, in, flags);
if (!finished) {
    NSLog(@"SMIME write CMS didn't succeed!");
    assert(false);
}

printf("cms encrypted: %s\n", temp);

NSLog(@"All succeeded!");
```

The OpenSSL reference uses a direct file output with the BIO.
This works but I can't use BIO_new_file() in objective-c... :-/

```
out = BIO_new_file("smencr.txt", "w");
if (!out)
    goto err;

/* Write out S/MIME message */
if (!SMIME_write_CMS(out, cms, in, flags))
    goto err;
```

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest trying to use SIZE-1, that way you are guaranteed that it is NULL terminated. Otherwise, it is possible that it is just over running the buffer.

```
out = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)temp, SIZE-1);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Edit:

When using `BIO_new_mem_buf()` it is a read only buffer, so you cannot write to it. If you want to write to memory use:

```
BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
```

Comment: Thanks, that was another problem but it didn't solve my aforementioned issue. :-/
Now I've used the BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()) instead of the BIO_new_mem_buf(). The msg is stored in there but I need it in a char* (lets say string). So I tried to BIO_read() it into a string using this: "unsigned char* temp = malloc(50000); memset(temp, 0, 50000); int size = BIO_read(out, temp, 50000);". 
This works btw. I can print it on the screen or save it in a file but it's really ugly because of the strings static size. Do you know how to determine the size of a BIO before read? (read returns the size...)

Comment: `long BIO_get_mem_data(BIO *b, char **pp)` sets pp to a pointer to the start of the memory BIOs data and returns the total amount of data available. It is implemented as a macro. That should help.